# big delay in loading a simple local html (no images) on UIWebView if running at xcode debugger

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

Right now we are experiencing a weird issue. We have a screen which contains a UIWebView to load a local html content. What I found out that if there could be a big delay (about 20 seconds to 50 seconds) to load up the screen after the methods viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear of that screen are called.  This only happens if we load the app into iPhone via xcode debugger and run it at xcode debugger. It won't happen if I run the app directly at the iPhone. If I change the UIWebView to a text view, we won't see this big delay.

Does anyone see similar issue before?

This really puzzles me quite a bit and it would be appreciated if anyone could shed some lights on this.

**[Edit]**
I add the logging for delegate method of UIWebView, all those call backs are called after those big delays.

> 2013/08/13 17:05:53|I|907|PolicyViewController|37| entering viewDidLoad
>
> 2013/08/13 17:05:53|I|907|PolicyViewController|58| exiting viewDidLoad
>
> 2013-08-13 17:06:49.590 [1885:907] Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
>
> 2013/08/13 17:06:49|I|907|PolicyView|107| entering webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest
>
> 2013/08/13 17:06:49|I|907|PolicyView|112| entering webViewDidStartLoad
>
> 2013/08/13 17:06:50|I|907|PolicyView|116| entering webViewDidFinishLoad

for the log file, you could clearly see a big delay (nearly 1 minute) between viewDidLoad and UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest method

**[Edit-2]** Attaching the thread screen shot when I pause the execution during that big delay ( the pause won't happen right away after I press the "Pause" button though)
[image: threads screen shot 1]
[image: threads screen shot 2]
[image: threads screen shot 3]

**[Edit-3]** we tested the same thing on a iPod touch which should use the same code at iPhone, we didn't reproduce this issue. So at this point it seems specific on iPhone.

Comment: Is it possible a Xcode bug here? by the way, we didn't see this at iPad although the code is slight different at iPad.

Comment: @PaulCezanne, thanks, I just attached threads screen shot. Could you elaborate what I need to check? Do you have any link for this?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks#mainthread

Comment: thanks, will do more reading around the links you sent. Any thoughts about how to explain that we would only see this at xcode debugger when running at iPhone. but NOT when we run directly at iPhone without xcode?

Comment: This might sound stupid, but check Internet/network speeds. Maybe using your iPhone (or whatever) with 3G or your Wifi is faster than the network connection you are using for you computer.

Comment: thanks @CaptJak.  I would think all the runs with xcode or without xcode should use the network at iPhone (only wifi).

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue, although I'm using an iPod Touch not an iPhone. Same deal, big delay when connected to the debugger, no delay when not connected. @windfly2006, did you ever get a resolution on this?

Comment: @dpassage, no solution for this at this point. Somehow we could not reproduce this on iPod touch. At this point, we kind of ignore it while keeping an eye on it since we haven't seen it on device without debugger yet and there seems not much we could do here.